# Copy an int by value in dart

Tags: dart, int

I was trying this:

```
  int i = 3;
  int b = 4;

  i =  b;

  print(identical(i, b)); //true
  print("$i - $b");       // i = 4 - b = 4

  b = 5;

  print(identical(i, b)); //false
  print("$i - $b");       //i = 4 - b = 5
```

How can I copy by value an int in Dart?

Thanks

Comment: Not possible since the `int` "object" are immutable. The reason is that `int` is not really an object but is handled like a normal `int` value in the Dart VM and compiled JavaScript. This is also why "Classes cannot extend, implement, or mix in int.": https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.7.2/dart-core/int-class.html . So you `int` variables are not really references to objects but are actual integer values.

Comment: The same applies to String, right?

Comment: `String` is actually objects you are referring to but are still immutable which are normal behavior in language like C# and Java. One reason for this is the ability to optimize String objects which are the same (so if the same String happens multiple time, we can just point to the same object and save some memory).

Comment: Why would you need to copy an `int` by value?  What would that mean?